Runners with different tags and one concurrent in one config.toml
I need to make two runners with different tags and one concurrent for both.
I want to come to this form:

concurrent = 70
1 runner (tag FOO)
2 runner (tag BOO, limit = 6
(about limit option))

That is, in total, only 70 jobs can be launched.
1st runner can launch a maximum of 70 jobs (by concurrent) 
2nd runner can launch a maximum of 6 jobs (by limit)
if the 2nd has already launched 6 jobs, the 1st will be able to launch a maximum of 64 jobs.
But in config.toml I can't specify tags for runners!
Maybe someone has ideas on how to implement this.
